# Phonegap save picture and lat/lon

Tags: cordova

I'm discussing with myself on how to save a picture AND its lat/lon in Phonegap.

I want to be able to take a picture, and then save the JPG as a file, and the lat/lon in a Web SQL database.

Then I can loop through all pictures in the db and show them on a map - when the pin is clicked, the picture should be shown.

How would you advice me to do that? The easiest way would have been to save the base64-encoded image in the Web SQL db, but it has a size limit.

Should I use FileWriter for this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Just get the values from the [Geolocation API](http://diveintohtml5.info/geolocation.html) when the user takes the picture, then save the picture wherever you want - but i don't recommend to save in the database - then, using the [google maps api](https://developers.google.com/maps/), you can get the picture lat/lon and mark it on the map. Quite simple!

Comment: I will have to save other stuff like a description, so I have to save the image and text/lat/lon different places (e.g. image in the filesystem and meta-info in a database). But don't know exactly how to do it.